# (macOS High Sierra, Qt C++) ERROR: "QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded"

Tags: c++, mysql, macos, qt

I'm struggling for a few days to connect my Qt project to MySql database without success. There are similar problems explained out there (eg. [LINK1](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/70301-Running-into-many-problems-setting-up-Qt-and-QMYSQL-(qmake-won-t-run-)), [LINK2](https://forum.qt.io/topic/106565/mysql-qt-create-plugin-mysql-for-qt-on-mac), [LINK3](http://www.webchef.de/blog/2019/07/qt-513-mysql-connection-on-macos-mojave.html))  but they didn't help me to solve my problem.

I use:
macOS High Sierra 
XAMPP 7.4.4, 
Qt Creator 5.14.2

I also set up my database using phpmyadmin. I also used: **"brew install mysql-client"** and it was successful.

I did a simple qt project that is supposed to connect to my database.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost"); //127.0.0.1
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("");
db.setDatabaseName("monitoringDB");

if (!db.open()) {
    qDebug() << "Couldn't open db";
} else {
    qDebug() << "DB opened!";
}
```

However when I try to run it I get the following error:

*QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded 

QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7*

I read much about the problem and I understand that I should changed dynamic shared libraries using **install_name_tool** but unfortunately I can't find on my computer any **libqsqlmysql.dylib** file that would need to be updated.. However I can find **libmysqlclient.21.dylib**

I would be very grateful if you have some suggestions because I think I'm really out of ideas.

Comment: Did you build and install the mysql plugin from qtbase sources, as described in LINK3?

Comment: Do you mean this MySQL project that would need to be edited and then build up? Yes, I was trying to go this way, but the problem was that I couldn’t find any project like that in my installation folders/files... Should it be normally installed together with Qt? Or can I download the project from somewhere (where?) and then edit it and build up?

Comment: It refers to the Qt source code, which should be available as “sources” or such in the installer, or as tarball (e.g. https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.14/5.14.2/single/). Or use git.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld - that was good advice! Yes, I downloaded those sources. After that I followed [LINK] (https://forum.qt.io/topic/80882/error-while-compiling-qt-mysql-driver/21), namely I did qmake on qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqldrivers.pro and I did qmake on qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql/mysql.pro, after that I

Comment: This is my edited comment: Yes, I downloaded those sources. After that I followed [LINK] (http://www.webchef.de/blog/2019/07/qt-513-mysql-connection-on-macos-mojave.html) namely I added those two rows at mysql.pro (INCLUDEPATH and QMAKE_LIBDIR). Next I followed [LINK] (https://forum.qt.io/topic/80882/error-while-compiling-qt-mysql-driver/21), namely I did qmake on qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqldrivers.pro and I did qmake on qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql/mysql.pro, after that I did 'make'. Next I copied newly created libqsqlmysql.dylib into .../clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers

Comment: The good thing is that I do not have "QMYSQL driver not loaded" error anymore, but unfortunatelly I still cannot connect to MySql database. I get the error: **"Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) QMYSQL: Unable to connect"**. I have XAMPP started up and running, including MySql database. I also checked that my databaseName, userName and password are correct. **Can anybody help in solving this problem?...**